# How do I print the values in following way?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id, basic_salary):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.basic_salary = basic_salary

    def calculate(self):
        return (0.1 * self.basic_salary) + (0.2 * self.basic_salary) + self.basic_salary


class Child(Parent):
    pass


c = Child("Rupali", 134, 34567)
print("Employee : {0.name} \t ID : {0.id} \t Gross Salary : {0.calculate}".format(self))
```

Error: print("Employee : {0.name} \t ID : {0.id} \t Gross Salary : {0.calculate}".format(self))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I want the program to print it in the following way:
Employee : Rupali   ID : 134    Gross Salary : 45677
How to do it?

Comment: why have you written `0.name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your print statement formatting is wrong. read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id, basic_salary):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.basic_salary = basic_salary

    def calculate(self):
        return (0.1 * self.basic_salary) + (0.2 * self.basic_salary) + self.basic_salary


class Child(Parent):
    pass


c = Child("Rupali", 134, 34567)
print("Employee : {} \t ID : {} \t Gross Salary : {}".format(c.name,c.id,c.calculate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing different types of string formatting. Try:

```
c = Child("Rupali", 134, 34567)
print(f"Employee : {c.name} \t ID : {c.id} \t Gross Salary : {c.calculate()}")

# Employee : Rupali      ID : 134    Gross Salary : 44937.1
```

This takes advantage of Python 3.6's new [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals).

If you're not using Python 3.6, you can use the other answer's `.format` approach.

Keep in mind as well that you can override your class's `__str__` method to do this for you.

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Employee : {self.name} \t ID : {self.id} \t Gross Salary : {self.calculate()}"

c = Child("Rupali", 134, 34567)
print(c)
# Employee : Rupali      ID : 134    Gross Salary : 44937.1
```